# Google Checkout: specifying a shipping address

Tags: asp.net, google-checkout

With Google Checkout, is there any way to pass in a default shipping address that can't be changed?

I don't want the user to change this as the tax and shipping options are already calculated in the application. Web services from google to my application aren't an option either for other reasons that I don't need to get into.

Thanks.

Edit

I'm using version 2.5, and the GCheckout project 2.5.0.3 (.Net sample code library) to generate the checkout button. I don't see any options on the CheckoutShoppingCartRequest object to specify a shipping address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there anyway of passing a shipping address to Google Checkout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360895/is-there-anyway-of-passing-a-shipping-address-to-google-checkout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a roundabout way, but I *think* you can add a merchant-calculated shipping method with your precalculated shipping, and set ShippingRestrictions on that method. Your restrictions can limit to certain zip codes, so if you limit it to *only* the zipcode that the user specified, it should prevent them using this shipping method against any other address.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but would make for a poor user experience. If the user chose a different shipping address they'd get a generic error from google about not shipping to that location.

Comment: I know, that's the best I can think of though. Checkout is designed so that either *you* handle the complete checkout process, or *it* does (including setting the shipping address).

Comment: Yeah, I think google did a poor job of this. I hate to say it, but PayPal handles this well. You can customize / override all of this. Thanks for the option - hopefully someone else has a cleaner solution!

Comment: I've done a pretty thorough review of options, and it seems that there aren't any reasonable ones.