# Is there anyway of passing a shipping address to Google Checkout?

Tags: google-checkout

I'm looking into integrating Google Checkout into our website. At the checkout stage of our website we calculate the delivery cost based on where they are shipping to, however it appears to me that the user could change the shipping address once they reach Google Checkout i.e the user could indicate on our website that they want it shipped down the road, and then at Google Checkout indicate they want it shipped to Australia!

Is there anyway of passing a shipping address across to Google Checkout, and then prevent the user from changing that address? Failing that, is it at minimum possible to pass the shipping address to GC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using "merchant-calculated shipping".

Merchant-calculated shipping allows you to wait until the buyer selects the shipping address for an order before you determine the availability and cost of different shipping options for that order.

You must provide a callback URL and Google Checkout will call you back with the final shipping address and request from you the available shipping methods and costs.

More info in this doc:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Merchant_Calculated_Shipping.html

Comment: Hi Mihai - you answered the question, it wasn't the solution I was hoping for but thats because from the looks of things Google Checkout doesnt offer the functionality we want as of yet. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If the order has been placed by this time, you should be OK - from http://checkout.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99746

> You may add shipping addresses to your
>   account or revise them at any time.
>   Changes cannot be applied to existing
>   orders; you will need to contact the
>   seller to request shipping address
>   updates

And

> Any changes you make to your shipping
>   address are not retroactive -- Once
>   the order is placed, any changes to
>   the order must be applied by the
>   seller. Contact the seller directly
>   with your request